# Update the createdAt column in Parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

When uploading a file to `Parse.com`, the `createdAt` column get set automatic.

I want to update the `createdAt` time, to the current time this func get set:

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"NorgeStory")
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(objID[(indexPath?.row)!]) {
            (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else if let gameScore = gameScore {
                gameScore["isPending"] = false
                gameScore["createdAt"] = self.currentDateTime
                gameScore.saveInBackground()
                gameScore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) in
                    if (success) {
                        // The score key has been incremented
                        print("Accepted post!")

                        let alert = UIAlertView()
                        alert.title = "Innlegg godkjennt!"
                        alert.message = "Innlegget er godkjennt."
                        alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                        alert.show()

                        self.queryStory()

                    } else {
                        // There was a problem, check error.description
                        print(error?.description)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
```

The `self.currentDateTime` is from: `let currentDateTime = NSDate()`

But somehow, the `createdAt` does not change at all.. How come? Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, but the field `createdAt` and `updatedAt` cannot be modified manually; https://www.parse.com/questions/can-i-modify-the-field-createdat

Try something like this:

1. Create a new column in [Parse.com](http://parse.com/), named ex: `modifiedAt` as an `NSDate`.
2. Change your code `gameScore["createdAt"]` to `gameScore["modifiedAt"]`.

Now that field will be updated as the same format as `createdAt`, and you can easy update the column as you would like.

Comment: Glad I could help you out! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't update the `createdAt` field (see [this Parse forum link](https://www.parse.com/questions/can-i-modify-the-field-createdat), where a Parse employee says that "createdAt and updatedAt fields cannot be manually modified". You should create a new Date column that you update instead.

Comment: Oh, hmm.. How would I get the same output as the `creadtedAt`?